# Wordpress plugin admin ajax returning 400 bad request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am writing a plugin and i am trying to submit an ajax request from the main plugin file which another file picks up and returns a response.

Code is below

**plugin.php**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#a-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
                url : ajaxurl,
                data : {
                    action : 'my_action',
                    whatever : '2'
                },
                method : 'POST',
                success : function( response ){ console.log(response) },
                error : function(error){ console.log(error) }
            })
  });
});
```

**form-submission.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

$whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
```

}

my ajax file is localized and readily available within the document so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

http://xxx.yyy/zzz/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

No matter how i play about with the jquery post it constantly returns a '400 bad request'... any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest you check the server side logs to see the exact error which is causing the 400 response. There's nothing obviously wrong in the tiny snippet of code that you've shown.

Comment: Were you logged-in when you tried the AJAX request? If not, then you need `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );` for users who're not logged-in to the site. Unless of course you actually wanted to limit the AJAX request to authenticated users only.

Comment: I was logged in, this should be for admin users only and is only accessible via the backend.

Comment: Try simulating the AJAX request by visiting `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action&whatever=1` and temporarily use `$_GET` in your `my_action()` function. Does it work (i.e. do you see the expected output)?

Comment: Returned 0, i moved everything from form-submission.php to my main plugin file as i dont see that this would cause an issue and this fixed the problem. I think im being a moron and my form-submission.php file is never actually used/called.

Comment: Nothing wrong with keeping this in a single file is there? can it still peform a request to the same file? it seems to have worked

Comment: This is my first day with wordpress so sorry if i sound stupid.. I take it as i'm using wordpress's admin-ajax, this is why it works and is not causing an issue as its handled by their native ajax handler and not actually being processed in my script as i added an action?

Comment: If you look at the `admin-ajax.php` file, you'd see this: `if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) )` which checks if there are "actions" hooked to the `'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action']` "action", which in your case is `wp_ajax_my_action`. And if none, then a '400' error is thrown (i.e. `wp_die( '0', 400 );` as you can see in the file). So maybe your "action" was added *after* that `do_action()`; that's why you got a `0` and the '400' error.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't fully answer your questions, but you can hook to an "action" from within any PHP files; just make sure the file is loaded - and that your hook is added - *before* WordPress fires the "action". And just to clarify, when I said 'that `do_action()`', I was referring to the `do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );` in the `admin-ajax.php` file. All the best.

Comment: wp_localize_script(
            'themescripts', // this needs to match the name of our enqueued script
            'myObj',      // the name of the object
            array('ajaxurl' => $admin_url,'baseurl'=>get_template_directory_uri()) // the property/value
          ); This is necessary so that it takes the variable ajaxurl in javascript